# AWS S3 Bucket - getSignedUrl PUT return a 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redux, jwt

i got a weird issue in my project were i can't manage to found what i did wrong. I am trying to upload an image to my blog and i am using the aws s3 config in order to do it. I believe that my configs are corrects but just in case i will add them there :

**here my cors config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

all my IAM policy and user api are in order and activated. Here is the code in my backend :

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: keys.aws.clientID,
  secretAccessKey: keys.aws.clientSecret,
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  region: "eu-west-3"
})

const router = express.Router()
// @route  GET api/posts/upload
// @desc   Upload an image on amazone server API
// @access Private
router.get(
  "/upload",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const key = `${req.user.id}/${uuid()}.jpeg`
    s3.getSignedUrl(
      "putObject",
      {
        Bucket: "bebeyogini",
        ContentType: "image/jpeg",
        Key: key
      },
      (err, url) => res.send({ key, url })
    )
  }
)
```

When i call the /upload endpoint it return a

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
```

that why in my frontend (in redux) i added a PUT where i am adding the content-type file in the headers. But still it doesn't work in this project

```
export const sendPost = (newPost, file, history) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(loading())
  const uploadConfig = await axios.get("/api/posts/upload")
  console.log(uploadConfig)
  console.log(uploadConfig.data)
  await axios.put(uploadConfig.data.url, file, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": file.type
    }
  })
  const res = await axios.post("/api/posts", {
    ...newPost,
    imageUrl: uploadConfig.data.key
  })
  history.push("/dashboard")
  dispatch({
    type: POSTS_FETCHED,
    payload: res.data
  })
}
```

I succedded few month ago in an other project in make the aws s3 working doing these same config and the only difference i had between both is that the one that worked out was setup with cookie session and this one is a jwt-token in the header.

If anyone have an idea... I am completly stuck!
here the repository

errors status:

```
bebeyogini.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/5bc0eca10743075fecb360f2/8bb4ff60-d8e7-11e8-ad9d-f776f418fd42.jpeg?Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIAMYTIX267RJ5E4A%2F20181026%2Feu-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181026T062242Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=943652af4bea7e8e0e6d0f97503ea997817e7d68e0540c599643d612d71fe693&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host:1 PUT https://bebeyogini.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/5bc0eca10743075fecb360f2/8bb4ff60-d8e7-11e8-ad9d-f776f418fd42.jpeg?Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIAMYTIX267RJ5E4A%2F20181026%2Feu-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181026T062242Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=943652af4bea7e8e0e6d0f97503ea997817e7d68e0540c599643d612d71fe693&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host 400 (Bad Request)
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)
```

https://github.com/erwanriou/bebeyogini

Comment: 400 has a number of potential causes, documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Comment: i updated the post with the errors status...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok after few night of suffering, i did found the solution of the probleme. Be aware that AWS S3 doesn't accept jwt bearer token included in his PUT request. So you have to disable it when doing the request. Here i could fix it on my frontside using the library axios...

```
export const sendPost = (values, file, history) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(loading())
  const uploadConfig = await axios.get("/api/posts/upload")
  delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]
  await axios.put(uploadConfig.data.url, file, {
    headers: {
      ContentType: file.type
    }
  })
  const token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken")
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token
  const res = await axios.post("/api/posts", {
    ...values,
    imageUrl: uploadConfig.data.key
  })
  dispatch({
    type: POSTS_FETCHED,
    payload: res.data
  })
  history.push("/dashboard")
}
```

Comment: This solved my issues. I was using Nuxt's built in `$axios` module which includes `Authorization` headers. I had to import and create a new axios instance.

Comment: this saved my time.

Comment: this has potentially saved me hours and hours of work. thank you.

Comment: this saved me a lot of hours, thank you so much

Comment: Javascript fetch api can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.` this mean your pre-signing data not match with your data what you want to upload.

Your signed data:

```
{
    Key: `${req.user.id}/${uuid()}.jpeg`
    ContentType: "image/jpeg",
}
```

Your file meta:

```
{
    Name: file.name
    ContentType: "image/jpeg",
}
```

`file.name` !== `${req.user.id}/${uuid()}.jpeg`

You can change the file name in client side to the same file name (what has been generated) on server side, or use opposite way

Comment: I see, that would explain it lot! I will try to update that right away!

Comment: Well, i look and i just can't figure how you could say my file meta is file.name
i verified again and again and i don't know what you mean by Name: file.name

Comment: `sendPost ` function  in you frontend, the second param named - `file`. This is a file object, `file.name` is the origin name of file (what has been upload form your computer).

Comment: Ok, in the action the PUT function i am using as first argument the uploadConfig.data.url where i am suppose to upload the data and then you say that in my second argument that is the file, it automatically detect the file.name event i don't want him to? I did try to setup the exact same name in backend by transforming the key = 'test.jpeg' and imported an image called 'test.jpeg' to make match this file.name but i did had the same error.

Comment: The thing is that using exactly this same UI and backend but setting up an authentification with cookies than jwt token, its work perfectly. But i want jwt because i don't want to do it only on navigators.... I don't know why but i think the authorization headers is doing something weird and aws s3 don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

As axios has JWT which cause 400 error. to avoid that we can use javascript fetch api.

Blow is code

```js
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file[0]);

const requestOptions = {
      method: "PUT",
      body: formData,
      redirect: "follow",
    };


const response = await fetch(presignedPutRequestUrl, requestOptions);
```

OR use [transformRequest](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config)

```js
await axios.put(putRequestUrl, file[0], {
      transformRequest: [
        (data, headers) => {
          delete headers.Authorization;
          return data;
        },
      ],
    });
```